# Метки: множественное или единственное число?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

На сайте присутствует множество меток как в единственном, так и во множественном числе (полужирным выделена основная метка):

- **[алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc)** и [алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b) *(синонимы)*
- [массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2) и **[массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b)** *(синонимы)*
- [сеть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c) и [сети](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8)
- [запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81) и [запросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b)
- [класс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81) и [классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b)
- [цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb) и [циклы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8b)
- [сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82) и [сайты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%8b)
- [поток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba) и **[потоки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)**, [thread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread)
- [скрипт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82) и [скрипты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%8b)
- [событие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [события](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f)
- [шаблон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd) и [шаблоны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8b)
- [шрифт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82) и [шрифты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b)
- [браузер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80) и [браузеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b)
- и так далее, всего 38 пар (или даже больше)

[Посмотреть полный список всех пар меток](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/312861/plural-singular-tags-russian).

На сайте единообразия и даже большинства нет: в одном случае больше вопросов у метки со множественным числом, в другом — с единственным. Как синонимы отмечены ничтожное меньшинство пар меток (а именно две самые популярные).

Какая метка должна быть основной, а какая — синонимом к основной?

Comment: Как мне кажется, сейчас самое время выбрать правильный ответ и переименовать метки.

Comment: **Важно!** С потоками в данный момент есть путаница между treads&streams. Нельзя просто переименовать, нужно разобрать и пометить вопросы вручную.

Answer (score 11):

По-моему, в большинстве случаев **следует использовать множественное число**, поскольку оно отражает некую общность и принадлежность к категории, а не частную ситуацию.

Множественное число лучше подходит для описания темы вопроса:

Вопрос о деталях алгоритма quicksort можно назвать «вопросом об алгоритмах» и пометить [алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b).

Вопрос о различных алгоритмах сортировки нельзя назвать «вопросом об алгоритме» и пометить [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc).

Исключение: Некоторые понятия существуют принципиально в единственном числе. Не нужно их трогать.

- [многопоточность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c),
- [кириллица](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0),
- [закрытие-вопросов](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2)...

Comment: опять же: поиск по метке и его результаты. логично, когда *множество результатов* носит *множественный* заголовок,  например, `алгоритмы`, а не *одиночный* `алгоритм`.

Comment: Я за то, чтобы "нормальным" вариантом считалось множественное число, а метки в единственном числе были просто алиасами-синонимами.

Answer (score 5):

Всегда использовать **единственное число** и не мучаться с выбором. В списке меток я не вижу ни одного случая, когда из-за числа возникает какая-то неоднозначность, или какое-то слово обычно используется во множественном числе.

Если всегда использовать единственное число, то значение метки становится простым и однозначным: вопрос касается, как минимум, одного «(название метки)».

Раздельное существование меток считаю недопустимым. Если я ищу алгоритм для массивов, я не хочу задумываться над тем, что было нужно автору вопроса: найти один алгоритм или сравнить несколько алгоритмов, обработать один массив или обработать несколько. Я просто хочу алгоритм для массивов.

На большом СО метки со множественным и единственным числом (отличающиеся на "s") считаются движком одинаковыми. Русский язык несколько сложнее, поэтому, вероятно, подобное удобство мы себе позволить не сможем. Надо просто вручную привести к тому формату, который успешно работает во всей сети Stack Exchange на протяжении многих лет.

Comment: «На большом СО метки со множественным и единственным числом (отличающиеся на "s") считаются движком одинаковыми» — не нашел подтверждения.

Comment: «успешно работает во всей сети Stack Exchange на протяжении многих лет.» — вовсе неверно, там нет доминирующего варианта. [methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods), [invariants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invariants), [tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags)

Answer (score 1):

Мне не кажется, что должно быть жёсткое правило насчёт числа. Лучше ориентироваться на смысл.

Для данных меток на первый взгляд лучше единственное число. Но возможны метки, где и единственное, и множественное число имеют смысл. Примеры:

[алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc): как найти наибольший отсортированный подмассив в массиве?
[алгоритмы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b): какой наиболее быстрый стабильный алгоритм сортировки?

[шрифт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82): как использовать кастомный шрифт на веб-странице?
[шрифты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d1%8b): какой шрифт под Ubuntu спроектирован с хорошим кернингом в области кириллицы?

[браузер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80): я пишу браузер, хорошая ли идея отказаться от поддержки плагинов (например, flash)?
[браузеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b): какие браузеры из популярных поддерживают CSS4?

(Кажется, это превращается в правило: поиск специфического экземпляра чего-то или работа с ним — единственное число, сравнение разных — множественное).

Comment: Когда вы спрашиваете "как сделать X?", вы не можете знать заранее, сколько способов вам предложат. Когда вы спрашиваете "какие X делают Y?" с замыслом проверять версию, вам могут предложить проверять доступность фичи в коде для любого X. И так далее. Вопрос не должен ограничивать число.

Comment: @Athari: Ну да. Я предлагаю к вопросу «как сделать X» единственное число (речь идёт об _одном_ браузере), а «какие Х» — множественное (речь идёт обо _всех_ или многих браузерах).

Comment: Это ужасно усложнит поиск. Тому, кто ищет вопрос, понадобится угадать, что было нужно ОПу: обсудить один алгоритм или сравнить несколько. Грань между этим очень тонкая, и явно не тянет на причину разделять метки.

Comment: @Athari: С другой стороны, если я вижу вопрос о сравнении алгоритмов, и хочу поискать другие сравнения, то я просто нажимаю на метку, и получаю именно их, а не запросы на «как мне найти третий по величине элемент?».

Comment: Это в идеальном мире, в котором все умеют читать ваши мысли и чётко следовать вашему алгоритму выбора правильной метки (я ваш алгоритм чётко не понимаю, кстати). А в реальном мире никто не будет заморачиваться с логикой подобной сложности при выборе метки. Вы готовы перетегать 50000 вопросов, а потом каждый день следить за соблюдением ваших правил? Я — нет. Вы — тоже. Вы вообще против редактирования вопросов ради тегов.

Comment: @Athari: Я не совсем против редактирования меток. Я против массового редактирования ради редактирования. Если вопрос улучшается (редактируется), то подправить при этом и метку должно быть правильно. В любом случае, оба подхода предполагают, что теги в существующих вопросах окажутся невалидными?

Comment: @Athari: Если юзер ставит неправильную метку — сам виноват. Если он вместо метки [c#] поставит [1с] — ССЗБ,

Comment: Добавление синонимов и массовое переименование — инструмент модератора, делается в пару нажатий и вопросы не апает. Разделение на единственное и множественное число согласно какой-то логике возможно только вручную. / Если юзер не различает язык — ОК, ССЗБ. Если не читает ваши мысли — в этом винить сложно.

Comment: Хотя в объединении, возможно, есть резон. Можно ли объединить так, чтобы не было автоматического превращения [тег] в [теги]? Если да, то пусть более точную метку ставит тот, кому небезаразлична семантика. Идея в том, чтобы обе метки сохранились.

Comment: Как бы дать точный инструмент тем, кому он интересен, но не заставлять им пользоваться.

Comment: Если теги отмечены как синонимы, то вы не сможете искать только по одному из тегов — будут выводиться все синонимы. Не представляю, как вы собираетесь использовать разделение по числу, если вашему правилу будет следовать ровно один человек — вы сами. Можно тогда сразу добавлять в запрос `[userid:NNN]`.

Comment: Мне казалось, что для сравнения браузеров метка [браузеры] (а не [браузер]) самоочевидна, разве нет?

Comment: Для меня самоочевидно, но, возможно, эта т. зр. не разделяется большинством. Устроим опрос?

Comment: Этот вопрос и есть опрос. Ваше мнение достаточно уникально, потому что я не разу не видел жалоб, что метки в разном числе считаются движком за синонимы.

Comment: Окей, ждём других мнений.

Comment: Мне кажется, что разница в значении между единственным и множественным числом трудноуловима. Очень сложно будет приучить пользователей к тому, чтобы они различали смыслы и использовали правильное число. Это неявное кодирование, и как все неявное, оно подвержено ошибкам.