# Методы, функции, процедуры

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Исключительно академический вопрос: Чем отличаются следующие понятия, следует ли их вообще различать?

- [метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4) (36), [методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b) (23)
- [функция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f) (16), [функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8) (257)
- [процедура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0) (0), [процедуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b) (20)

Как минимум нужно **синонимизировать единственное и множественное число**. Что касается самих определений: видел различные, в том числе по критерию принимаемых параметров и возвращаемого значения. А ещё критерий «в Java — методы, а в JS – функции».

Может ли кто-нибудь компетентный **сделать описания для этих меток**, чтобы их можно было различать?

Comment: Еще [tag:замыкание] и [tag:замыкания]. Вообще, я всеми руками за унификацию этого термина, но поскольку каждый язык пропагандирует свое именование, то, как говорится, не в этой жизни. У англичан есть понятие [callable unit](http://www.eac.gov/vvsg/glossary.aspx), но я не думаю, что все теги нужно приводить к нему, потому что это может дизориентировать пользователя. Также есть понятие "хранимая процедура", а "функция" - это вообще математический термин.

Comment: На SO, кстати, тоже бардак с ними, но там хотя бы есть нормальное описание для метки ["methods"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/methods/info). Меня только смущает `Block` в FOTRAN - всегда думал, что там `Subroutine`, но я не работал с ним.

Comment: Про единственное/множественное число - это отдельный глобальный вопрос, по которому пока нет общего мнения: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327/

Answer (score 3):

Если правильно помню, различие есть между этими понятиями:

- **метод:** функция или процедура, принадлежащая классу.
- **функция:** возвращает результат
- **процедура:** не возвращает результат

Но в разных языках бывает по-другому. В Pascal, например, есть ситаксическое различие между функциями и процедурами, и методов нет. В JavaScript, все называются функции, хотя функции в `prototype` тоже называются методы. В SQL, "хранимые процедуры" иногда могут возвращать результаты. В матемаике, функция имеет формальное определение, отдельно от значения в мире программирования.

Я за синонимизацию (?) этих меток, потому что нет универсальных определений этих понятий, и они все таки довольно близкие. Я не вижу, в чем здесь может быть выгода их различать.

Comment: Метки введены как раз для различия, и тут оно есть (хотя и зависит от языка). Иначе можно вообще все заменить убер-меткой [it] ;-)

Comment: В SQL и "пользовательские функции" бывают.

Answer (score 3):

**За множественное число**

**Синонимизацию – рассмотреть, когда будут сделаны описания для меток.**

Если авторы описаний смогут объяснить детали **использования** каждой метки — оставить самостоятельными.

Если там будут только теоретические различия вроде «возвращает» или «не возвращает» — синонимизировать к одной.

Answer (score 2):

Хоть термины и обозначают совершенно разное, но на мой взгляд, участники используют их совершенно произвольно. Уверен, практически все вопросы касающиеся этих меток, можно рассмотреть как [ооп](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%be%d0%bf) либо аналогичных.

В случае если мы не планируем объединять все метки, а только создавать синоним между множественным и единственным числом, то стоит использовать единственное число, согласно [этому ответу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329/6).

Comment: Пока что в этом ответе нет принятого решения, да и баланс голосов уже изменился. Судя по сумме голосов по модулю, в голосовании приняло участие не более 4х человек. Думаю, недостаточно для результата. Может быть, в featured?

Answer (score 0):

**За удаление этих меток**

Какой смысл имеют подобные метки на сайте для программистов? [функция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f),[процедура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0),[метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4),[класс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81) - это всё детали реализации того или иного языка программирования. И все эти понятия покрываются тегом соответствующего языка. Сами по себе эти метки бесполезны.

Comment: Данные метки могут быть полезны в вопросах про синтаксис написания методов функций или процедур. Например "как в Delphi написать виртуальную процедуру и чем она отличается от абстрактной?" "Почему не работает перегрузка метода ABC у структуры?" "Какие ограничения у методов класса помощника".

Comment: @KromStern для этих вопросов теги должны быть [полиморфизм] и [перегрузка]

Comment: +1, этим метки аналогичны метке "код" и "программирование". Если с процедурами/функциями связана какая-то проблема, должна использоваться метка для этой проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

**Против синонимизации**, т.к. различия все же есть, пускай и незначительные.

**За множественное число**, т.к. вряд ли есть вопросы про *конкретные* методы или функции.

И за зачистку тэгов с вопросов, где автор просит написать за него или отдебажить типа:

- [Разделяй и властвуй: подсчет количества инверсий в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/375825/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)
- [Золотое сечение МО](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264142/%d0%97%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%9c%d0%9e)

Comment: "Функции", кроме того, имеют чисто математическое значение, чего нельзя сказать о "методах" и "процедурах". Думаю, правильно пока что оставить все три, и добавить в "функции", что они ещё и математические, тогда вопрос а-ля "вычисление функции методом Бла-бла" получит основную метку "функции" и вторую - некоего ЯП, который используется для вычислений.

Comment: Второй про золотое сечение понятен, я на него там отвечал даже, только я тогда был не в курсе правил сообщества и меня заминусовали. Да, и в нем вопрос про "методы" не имеет отношения к методам как функциям, он имеет отношение к метопту: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Щас прибью на нем тег

Comment: @Vesper: «тогда вопрос а-ля "вычисление функции методом Бла-бла" получит основную метку "функции" и вторую - некоего ЯП, который используется для вычислений.» – а что делает метку основной?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Кстати вопрос интересный - пока не понимаю, что. Больше всего похоже, что последняя в списке под вопросом метка "основная", т.е. светится в заголовке окна. По мне, правда, правильнее считать основной первую.

Comment: @Vesper: а я думал, что самая популярная...

Comment: @NickVolynkin Нет, кстати - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428196/ сверкает меткой `cmd`, а метка `xml` её по популярности перекрывает. Да и отображается метка не первой и не последней. Хм-м-м-м.

Comment: Запросил на мете http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260870/how-to-select-what-tag-should-be-primary-for-the-question ибо вопрос любопытный, и эквивалент не найден.

Comment: Ответ, оказывается, чуть хитрее http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title - берутся два самых популярных тега из вопроса, если один из тегов есть в вопросе как текст, вставляется второй. Если есть оба, опять-таки (похоже, по последнему примеру в ответе) вставляется второй.