# Сколько [методов] нам нужно?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

У нас есть [метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4) и [методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b) отвечающие за одно и то же.

Предложение - слить / синонимизировать эти метки.

P.S. Вопрос обсуждался в схожем ключе ранее - [Методы, функции, процедуры](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/814)

Comment: Как мы до сих пор их не заметили и не объединили, даже удивительно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin может стоит начать с добавления описания метки, я что то с ходу даже не придумаю вопрос в котором необходима данная метка

Comment: @Bald метка, очевидно, нужна вопросам про работу с методами. Их объявления, поведение, и т.п.

Comment: @Kromster как-то она подозрительно похожа на мета-метку )

Comment: тогда что есть [tag:метод]?

Comment: @NickVolynkin по идее она ничем не хуже функций, классов, переменных, интерфейсов (ISomething), и т.п. Тут желательно комплексное решение. Я считаю что эти метки нужны - вреда от них нет.

Comment: @Bald посмотрите вопросы - они все про особенности работы с методами

Comment: ага а там еще есть метка [tag:параметры]. я согласен с @NickVolynkin по поводу что сильно похоже на мета-метку, как то слишком расплывчато... а еще есть метка [tag:процедуры] наверно тоже можно синонимизировать

Comment: @Bald [tag:параметры] это тоже валидная метка - можно задать не один вопрос про особенности работы с in/out и другими вариантами передачи параметров в разных ЯП. Процедуры .. это может и лишнее. Но опять же - вреда не несет.

Comment: @Kromster мы уже проводили почти такое же голосование около года назад: [Методы, функции, процедуры](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b?lq=1)

Comment: @NickVolynkin консенсуса там не было, поэтому предлагаю не мешать все в кучу. А пока что просто синонимизировать "методы" )

Answer (score 4):

**Нам вообще не нужно [методов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2).**

Обе являются мета-метками и не добавляют информации в вопрос. В `/dev/null` их.

Answer (score 3):

**[методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b) сделать основной.**

Как показывает голосование на Мете - [множественное число предпочтительнее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327/181472).

---

2 июля синонимизировал и объединил метки, теперь [методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b) является основной.

Answer (score 0):

[метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4) сделать основным. Единственное число предпочтительнее.

Comment: *"Восстановил" вариант для голосования. Блин, вы в следующий раз голосование сразу с одним вариантом ответа устраивайте, чтобы наверняка!*

Comment: *чёрт, ты спалил наш план! )))*