# Синонимы для метки [кодировка]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать метки [encodings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encodings), [encoding](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding), [кодировки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8) в метку [кодировка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Заметил, что по метке [encoding] были вопросы по шифрованию, перевесил на них метку [шифрование]. Все оставшиеся вопросы с [encoding] теперь относятся только к вопросам о кодировке

Comment: Что-то глухо в голосовании.

Comment: Тимофей, предлагаю вам пойти тем же путем, что я прошел с юнит-тестами. Переставьте метки на вопросах с заплюсованными ответами, чтобы появились голосующие участники. Потом совместным голосованием закроете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, можно попробовать.

Comment: троих участников я напрямую призывал к голосованию в комментариях, давал ссылку, ещё двоим писал в общем чате. Из этих пятерых какие-то 4 проголосовали.

Answer (score 3):

У нас есть довольно спорное [голосование о числе в названиях меток](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/571/181472). Не стоит ли здесь выбрать множественное число?

- Основная метка: [кодировки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)
- Синонимы: [кодировка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0), [encoding](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encoding), [encodings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encodings)

Ответ дан на правах адвоката дьявола.