# Синоним trigger -> триггеры

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки

Меткой [trigger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trigger) помечено 24 вопроса, меткой [триггеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b) помечено 11 вопросов.
Предлагаю оставить русскую метку [триггеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b), а [trigger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trigger) сделать синонимом.

Comment: Не нравится мне вообще эта метка... Триггеры как бы не только в СУБД бывают.

Comment: В некоторых языках триггером называют любой обработчик события. Или даже любую подпрограмму. А уж в схемотехнике...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да, тоже такие мысли посещали, однако, посмотрев вопросы, не обнаружил ни одного, который бы не был посвящен базам данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объединил и добавил синоним «триггер», который стал основной меткой, [согласно голосованию о множественном и единственном числе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327/).