# Массивы и строки в единственном числе

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Вроде как [решили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/571/176217) использовать множественное число в качестве основных меток. Но почему тогда [строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8) и [массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b) не являются таковыми? Может быть это стоит исправить, или это тот редкий случай, что исключение вида:

> Некоторые понятия существуют принципиально в единственном числе. Не нужно их трогать.

вступает в силу? Но я бы так не сказал.

Comment: Вот "многопоточность" или "безопасность" не имеют смысла во множественном числе. А два массива по три строки вполне имеют смысл.

Comment: Переобъединил в нужную сторону. Пока что в заголовке страницы по ссылке осталось единственное число, но это должен быть кэш.

Comment: @NickVolynkin странно, конечно. У вопросов мгновенно подхватывается изменение, а страница "по метке" - нет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ещё вижу [tag:матрица] и [tag:матрицы]. [tag:сравнение] тоже вызывает вопросы.

Comment: Сравнение — вообще нелепая какая-то метка. С трудом могу себе представить книгу или статью про сравнения.

Comment: @NickVolynkin с [tag:вектор] тоже вопрос хороший.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Объедините [tag:матрица] c [tag:матрицы]?