# Является ли Мета набором правил, обязательных к исполнению?

Tags: поддержка, мета, правила

Я часто вижу призывы "давайте вынесем спорный вопрос на мету", однако я не понимаю как это может помочь.

Даже если самый заплюсованный вопрос становится новым правилом, то как пользователи должны узнать об этом новом правиле? На мете - сотни вопросов, никто не будет читать это всё. К тому же есть мета мет (английская, для всего SE) и там тоже что-то написано.

Comment: Связанные вопросы по данной теме: «[Праймериз для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6876/6)», «[Альтернативный регламент для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6896/)» и «[Как создать вопрос–инициативу?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6835/)»

Answer (score 12):

На мой взгляд — да, по крайней мере, так должно быть. Мета является той самой «сходкой», на которой провозглашаются принципы, принимаются новые законы и отменяются старые. Точно так же, по моему мнению, *любое решение, влияющее на сообщество, должно пройти одобрение сообщества на Мете*.

Мета — это наша прямая демократия.

Доносить до юзеров решение просто: нужно дать им ссылку на метаобсуждение.

---

Отдельный вопрос состоит в том, что делать, если решение на нашей Мете частично или полностью противоречит решению на Метамете или мнению представителей компании. Ответа на этот вопрос я не знаю.

---

**Запоздалый PS**: К сожалению, «демократия», как я её себе представлял на момент написания этого ответа, вовсе не работает. Приношу свои извинения тем, кому этот ответ дал неверное представление о том, как устроено данное сообщество. Смотрите продолжение и развитие обсуждения в более позднем вопросе [Границы демократических процедур](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7221/10105).

Comment: но разве все юзеры (в т.ч. новые) обязаны читать мету и помнить что на ней написано? У нас так скоро мета-юристы появятся, которые будут нужны потому что обычные юзеры не в состоянии запомнить все правила

Comment: @Abyx: Новые юзеры могут и не знать правил, да. Тогда если они что-то делают не так по незнанию, им кто-нибудь укажет пост на Мете, и они узнают.

Comment: @Abyx: До мета-юристов ещё далеко. Ну и если законы слишком сложные, соберёмся на Мете и упростим.

Comment: @VladD Поддержку обеими руками. Единственное, есть нюанс. Ранее мы не фиксировали принятие решений сообществом. То есть договорились и двинулись дальше, но начали появляться случае, когда по прошествию длительного времени сумма голосов на ответах изменялась! Например, [как это было с единственным/множественным числом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327/). Мне кажется, с сего момента надо использовать историческую блокировку и только такие вопросы в будущем считать «закрепленными правилами». Сейчас, конечно, так делать нельзя, ибо большенство решений не имеют блокировку.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Хорошая идея. В любом случае, если кто-то захочет _изменить_ правила, он должен открыть _новый_ вопрос.

Comment: @VladD Также я бы подчеркнул, что наиболее базовые правила продублированы в [справочном центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @Abyx добавим метку [language-lawyer] на Мету значит.