# Границы демократических процедур

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, вопросы, правила, мета

Мне казалось, что я достаточно хорошо знаю правила сайта, однако не так давно я понял, что мои представления либо были изначально ошибочны, либо политика сайта неожиданно поменялась.

[Управляющий сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/213987) в программном ответе недавно писал:

> Вопросы управления сайтом и сообществом ... делятся на:
>
> - Вопросы, решения в которых принимают участники демократически.
> - Вопросы, решения в которых принимает компания единолично, опираясь на отзывы сообщества.

И признавая, что "провести черту между этими понятиями крайне сложно" оставляет эти вопросы за кадром.

Я бы хотел уточнить, какие вопросы на мете к какому уровню относятся. Это основной посыл моего поста:

> Какие конкретно вопросы решает сообщество? Есть ли такой список?

Постулируется, что "Понятие «решение принято большинством голосов» не применимо на сайтах Stack Exchange как минимум к правилам сообщества.", а насколько применимо это к вопросам из списка "отданы на установление сообществу"?

Какой механизм подведения итогов? Кем он осуществляется? Как фиксируется принятое решение? Является ли результат демократического голосования на мете обязательным к исполнению? То есть должно ли каждое голосование на мете приводить к итогу?

Я не видел, чтобы в вопросах явно отмечалось "по этому вопросу будет принято решение администрации и, по возможности, учтены пожелания участников". (Понимаю, что участников много и желать могут разного).

Я не видел, чтобы управляющий сообществом или один из избранных сообществом модераторов производил процедуру подведения итогов. Я в своё время поддерживал идею накладывать историческую блокировку и явно выделять принятое решение с датой введения в действие (скажем, через месяц).

Возможно, что нам нужен некий институт как в википедии принят институт подводящих итоги. И логично, что если вопросы отданы на откуп сообществу, то подводящий итоги должен быть кем-либо не из числа администрации.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил - является ли результат "демократического" голосования на мете обязательным к исполнению. - должно ли каждое голосование на мете приводить к итогу?

Comment: т.е. есть ли *реальная* проблема в отсутствии жесткого итога по некоторым вопросам? которую стоило бы чинить такими жесткими мерами как отключение дальнейшего голосования (через блокировку).

Comment: @PashaPash Дельное замечание. Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Связанный вопрос - [Является ли Мета набором правил, обязательных к исполнению?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6735/227465) было бы здорово получить ответ на него также и от представителя компании, а не только от представителя сообщества более подробно чем [этот комментарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6735/Является-ли-Мета-набором-правил-обязательных-к-исполнению#comment26503_6737).

Answer (score 7):

#### Границы демократических процедур

Крайне важно понимать, что такое «демократия» в рамках нашего сообщества и как она реализуется на сайте.

[Согласно Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F):

> Демократия — политический режим, в **основе которого лежит метод коллективного принятия решений** с равным воздействием участников на исход процесса или на его существенные стадии.

<sub>Выделение мое.</sub>

Следует отметить, что у нас нет и не может быть «политического режима», в прямом понимании этого термина, потому что платформа (движок сайта) создана для накопления знаний в кристаллизированном виде, а не для принятия коллективных решений.

#### В чем суть демократии на сайте? — Управление сообществом!

Ниже представлены основные демократические процессы в сообществе (процессы, в основе которых лежит метод коллективного принятия решений), которые критически важны для миссии проекта.

- **Коллективное управление содержимым сайта** (демократическое управление). Stack Overflow создается и управляется самим сообществом. Любой участник при желании может внести свой вклад в модерирование сайта отталкиваясь от того, как он понимает миссию проекта и правила сообщесвта. Это достигается за счет автоматически выдаваемых [привилегий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/) системой по достижению участником заданного [уровня репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).
- **Выборы модераторов сообщества из числа участников** (демократическое голосование). Модераторы не назначаются, а избираются сообществом. Модераторы — это не те люди, которые «решают» за других, это в первую очередь ответственные, наиболее опытные участники, [обрабатывающие исключительных ситуаций, которые не должны возникать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6) при «правильном использовании сайта».

*Демократия на Stack Overflow основывается на том, что любой желающий имеет возможность непосредственно влиять на жизнь сообщества и содержимое сайта.*

#### Самоуправление и самоопределение

Демократия на сайте (необходимые для этого технические возможности) реализована в движке исключительно в разрезе управлением содержимым сайта и сообществом, в том числе и выборы модераторов. В Stack Overflow (компании) мы глубоко верим в саморегулируемые системы и максимально возможное самоуправление в сообществе: с первого дня существования сайта мы придерживались идеи, что сайт создается и управляется самим участниками. Все «инструменты демократии» реализованы в движке и доступны участникам в рамках *основного сайта*. В то же время избранные модераторы имеют необходимые привилегии также и на Мете. В чате модераторы тоже имеют дополнительные привилегии для эффективной модерации. Все эти инструменты нужны для демократии в контексте организации самоуправления в сообществе.

Вы можете найти больше информации по теме в ответе на вопрос «[Что если понимание правил не совпадает с общепринятым? Есть ли у модераторов “амулет” и можно ли его забрать через Мету?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7411/6)».

#### Мета — это место для диалога

В общем случае, Мета — это площадка для обсуждений, а не для принятия решений. На Мете невозможно принять какое–либо «демократическое решение» утвержденное и с печатью, так как в движке нет нужных инструментов. Мы это детально рассмотрели буквально полгода назад в серии дискуссий (начать чтение можно с ответа на вопрос «[Альтернативный регламент для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/6)», где рассказывается как именно строен процесс принятия решений).

Про распределение голосов мы знаем, что даже на основном сайте принятый ответ (решение вопроса) может отличаться от ответа с наибольшим рейтингом: голоса на сайте нужны не для принятия ответов, а для сортировки содержимого сообществом. Исключительно для обеспечения демократической процедуры выбора модераторов через голосование, на сайте были созданы узкоспециализированные технические решения, а также введены жестко регламентированные процессы, привязанные к технической реализации. Выборы модераторов голосованием — это не вопрос на Мете, это большая подсистема со своими правилами.

Все это происходит потому что Мета проектировалась для дискуссий: о практиках модерирования сайта, о правилах сообщества и двустороннему взаимодействию компании–разработчика и сообщества. Для дискуссии и отзывов, но не принятия решений.

С другой стороны, соглашусь, что когда компания–разработчик интересуется мнением сообщества, то по результатам реализации (а лучше еще сразу после обсуждения) следует давать знать, какой подход был выбран в итоге и почему. Замечу, что на сегодняшний момент этот процесс может быть крайне долгий: необходимо все рассмотреть, перевести результаты на английский язык для предоставления коллегам, через какое–то время ответственный сотрудник на это посмотрит, задаст какой–то приоритет и когда–то это получит реализацию (или нет). Если вы знаете о подобных вопросах, пожалуйста, напишите о них мне или модераторам. Мы постараемся внести ясность.

#### Убеждение доводам

Наиболее заинтересованные в развитии проекта участники предлагают инициативы на Мете. Отзыв по инициативе может опубликовать любой участник сообщества, где доводами и логическими выкладками он может показать положительные и отрицательные стороны предложения. Подобные отзывы критически важны и помогают оценить инициативу со многих сторон еще до реализации.

Результат инициативы может быть разный. Например:

- Простое [обсуждение всплесков агрессии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/535/6) стало новым [разделом справки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly).
- [Инициатива ассоциации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/6) стало сторонним приложением, которое частично реализовано в движке и ждет полной реализации.
- [Тема инспекции кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/6) вошла в тематику сообщества.
- Как я вижу, метки до сих пор используются [и в множественном лице, и в единственном](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327/6).

Замечу, что в тех инициативах, которые предельно ясны, в обосновании правильности которых сложно усомниться, вне зависимости от того подведен итог или нет, участники следует лучшему предложенному решению.

Не в одной из выше приведенных инициатив не принималось решение на основе распределение голосов. На самом деле, если разобраться, то за всю историю сообщества, я могу вспомнить два случая принятия решения на основе голосов. Причем, в одном случае все закончилось совсем плохо, во втором — решения не совсем всегда принимаются на основе распределения голосов:

1. Голосование по выбору владельцев общей комнаты. Потерпело фиаско из за отсутствия процессов, которые обязательно должны быть во время любых выборов.
2. Голосование по переводам. На самом деле, и в этом случае подобный подход неверен, так как далеко не у всех из принимающих участия хороший литературный язык (багаж знаний, отталкиваясь от которого можно принимать взвешенные решения в данном вопросе), кому–то вообще нравится самый юмористический вариант. Голосование по выбору перевода заканчивается успешно, только когда в нем участвуют несколько хорошо разбирающихся в теме участников и, по сути, ответы нужны для сбора различных вариантов.

Как можно видеть, принятие решений на основе распределения голосов в ответах на Мете — это не лучшая практика. От нее следует *полностью* отказаться, так как Мета для этого не предназначена. Решения следует принимать на основе логических выкладок и доводов.

Answer (score 7):

Позвольте мне  сделать резюме ответа КМ, как я его понял, и дополнить своими уточнениями.

На сайте нет демократии в привычном понимании этого слова. Есть лишь некоторые демократические элементы.

Этими элементами являются:

- Модерация контента доступными начиная с некоторого порога репутации средствами: закрытие и повторное открытие вопросов. По сути, улучшение контента.
- Выборы* модераторов свободным голосованием.

  - Однако, модератор может быть снят администрацией.
- Возможность внести предложение на Мете об улучшении правил.

[Создание и правка контента, а также его оценивание голосами «за» и «против», согласно комментарию КМ, не является частью демократических процедур, поэтому я убрал первый пункт перечисления.]

---

Давайте остановимся ещё на том, каких демократических элементов на сайте *нет*.

- Сообщество не может изменить правила. Голоса, отданные за правила, не являются обязывающими кого-либо из администрации что-либо делать. Как бы сообщество не голосовало за то или иное изменение, от этого ничего не зависит.

  - Сообщество лишь может попытаться убедить менеджера SO по его доброй воле поменять правила. Вы должны придумать аргументы, которые убедят менеджмент, а не сообщество.
- Правилами считаются также посты администрации на различного рода Метах. Правила, не переведённые на русский язык, считаются тем не менее действующими.
- Правила не локализуемы: правила, созданные для англоязычного сообщества, действуют и для нашего сообщества.
- Более того, даже трактовка существующих правил — исключительная прерогатива администрации. В частности, является ли та или иная фраза оскорблением, определяется лишь администрацией.
- Определение необходимости выборов и назначение их даты — прерогатива администрации.
- Сообщество не можете требовать от модератора выполнять предвыборную программу. Сообщество не может снять модератора, если он вдруг перестанет сообществу нравиться или станет вредить**.

  - Вы, однако, можете попробовать убедить администрацию в том, что модератор плохой. Решение всё равно лежит на администрации, вы можете только просить.
- Наоборот, администрация имеет право снять избранного модератора, руководствуясь лишь своими внутренними правилами, и вы не можете никак на это повлиять, разве что очень сильно попросить.

  - Правила, в принципе, известны, но трактовка их вам не подвластна (не говоря уже об изменении)
- Все остальные выборные должности, например, владельцы комнат, могут быть также сняты руководством без учёта мнения сообщества.

---

Надеюсь, я правильно изложил факты. Поправки и дополнения к этому посту приветствуются, дополнение мотивацией тех или иных решений — нет.

---

*Если только модератор не был забанен администрацией.

**Это гипотетическое предположение, я не имею в виду какую-либо конкретную ситуацию или происшествие.

Comment: Я вот одного не понимаю. Как право создать контент вдруг стало огромной важности демократической процедурой, как вам ловко продали эту ценность и идею. Зашёл на форум - запостил вопрос, язык не повернётся говорить о демократии в таком контексте. Зашёл на so, создать вопрос - это сразу не просто действие, а целая Большая Демократическая Процедура. Ну как так?

Comment: @AK: Да, я тоже не считаю создание контента демократическим элементом. Но я так понял ответ КМа, что это является их частью.

Comment: @VladD Вы не верно поняли про содержимое. Создание содержимого != управление содержимым. Суть демократии — коллективное принятие решений. На сайте демократия лежит в разрезе принятия решения по управлению содержимым (не созданию, а управлению). Смысл в том, что каждый участник может принять участие в решение по любому вопросу. «Каждый участник может» — права на управления выдает система автоматически, в зависимости от уровня репутации. Прав много, они разные https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. Эта мысль про коллективное управление (модерацию) сайта. Именно об этом я написал в ответе.

Comment: «Сообщество не может изменить правила» — само по себе в вакууме — нет. С другой стороны сообщество может изменить правила убедив в необходимости изменений ответственных лиц.

Comment: «Вы не можете снять модератора, **если он вдруг перестанет вам нравиться.**» — нет, не можете, **если он перестал лично вам нравится**. Модераторы нужны, не для того, чтобы нравится. [Их выбирают для помощи сообществу в исключительных ситуациях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/6). С дугой стороны, вы можете вынести на обсуждение отзыв прав за нарушение правил сообщества. Реальный пример: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1777/6. Пожалуйста, перед этим напишите управляющему. Если ситуация однозначная, то модератор будет снят без публичных обсуждений.

Comment: «Более того, даже трактовка существующих правил — исключительная прерогатива администрации.» — В реальности, люди более или менее одинаково смотрят на вещи. Если правило трактуется по разному автором правила и участниками, то, с большой вероятностью, существует проблема, как минимум, в формулировке. Очень важно понимать, что ассистирующий сообществу сотрудник не всегда является автором правила и может понимать его «своеобразно». Это исправляется через ошибки и указание на них либо в личных сообщениях, либо на Мете. Реальный пример: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/6

Comment: «... администрация имеет право снять избранного модератора, **руководствуясь лишь своими внутренними правилами**..» — эти правила в публичном доступе и известны сообществу до проведения выборов. Основа этих правил — общие для всех участников правила, плюс несколько специфичных правил исключительно для модераторов (а–ля модерировать и не игнорировать вопросы других модераторов). Подчеркну, я вижу акцент на «**своими внутренними правилами**», но все правила в общем доступе (даже текст соглашение, на сколько я знаю).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Внёс в ответ ваши дополнения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: Очень часто я видел «своеобразное» понимание правил, о чём поднимал вопрос в чате.

Comment: @VladD Пожалуйста, перенесите все моменты неверного понимания правил на Мету. Уверен, вместе мы найдем правду и исправим недочеты.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: У меня не осталось конкретных записей, могу лишь вспомнить, что три месяца назад у меня лично были вопросы к трактовке «вредоносного шума» и «агрессии». Я бы хотел, чтобы кто-то, более радеющий за сайт, чем я сейчас, поднял эти вопросы и отстаивал _альтернативную_ точку зрения.

Comment: `или станет вредить` - если кто-либо из модераторов станет откровенно вредить, что помешает сообществу, во главе с КМ его снять? Напомню, модераторы не являются ни сотрудниками компании, ни зятьями директоров и т.п. Почему Вы считаете, компания пожелает оставить модератора, который вредит сообществу?

Comment: @VladD Про трактовку агрессии, если я вас правильно понял (в контексте правила дружелюбия), в скором будущем появится страница, так называемых норм поведения («code of conduct»). Она должна разъяснить этот момент. Сейчас эта страница полных ходом обсуждается на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/274323).

Comment: @vp_arth: В ситуации, когда цели и позиции сообщества и администрации расходятся, модератор вполне может «вредить сообществу» с точки зрения сообщества, и «усмирять отдельных негодяев и зачинщиков» с точки зрения администрации. Возможна такая ситуация, чисто теоретически?

Comment: @VladD, в подобной ситуации - [meta-tag:модераторский-произвол] - меньшая из проблем. Конфликт целей и позиций нужно решать. Или кина не будет.

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что "когда цели и позиции сообщества и администрации расходятся" - branch закрывается. Вы думаете иначе?

Comment: @vp_arth: Теоретически — да. А практически, это может быть решено администрацией способами, которые обговариваются _не здесь_.