# Синонимизировать и объединить [матрицы]

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метки [матрица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0) и [матрицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b). Предлагаю их объединить и основной сделать [матрицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b), так как мы [предпочитаем множественное число](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово, [матрицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b) основной.

```
updating post history, 141 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 147 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 134 rows affected
destroying 'матрица': [матрица] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for master tag, new count: 202
tag remapping of [матрицы] and [матрица] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
2 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: Какой любопытный лог

Comment: `total: 1 tags deleted` можно заводить баг с меткой [plurals]