# Объединить метки [матрицы] и [matrix]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Ранее [объединяли](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8067/317064) [матрицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b) и [матрица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0). Думаю, так же стоит объединить [матрицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b) и [matrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrix).

[матрицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b) - [236 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B).

[matrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrix) - [36 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matrix).

Comment: Тут, кстати, есть нюанс, что Matrix есть ещё такой протокол/мессенджер (правда, вопросов по нему скорее всего (ещё) нет)

Comment: @andreymal Matrix ещё есть от AG Software - C# либа для работы с XMPP (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По аналогии с [Синонимизировать и объединить [матрицы]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8063/15479).

Основной нужно сделать [матрицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b).