# Синонимизировать метки [окно] и [окна]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки, которые похожи даже по названию:

- [окно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be) (49 вопросов)
- [окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0) (38 вопросов).

Описания ни у той, ни у другой нет.

Предлагаю сделать эти метки синонимами (главная метка - [окно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be),
по предложеню @αλεχολυτ).

Comment: Окно - это то, что в квартире, а окна - программа на тнт)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а может "окна" — это про MS Windows. А "окно" про виджет верхнего уровня.

Comment: В какую сторону объединить предлагается?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ думаю, что лучше объединить эти метки под меткой "окна", как-то логичнее звучит в качестве названия метки.

Comment: Мини-проверка - Кто у нас тут "специалист по окнам"? А может быть вопрос с единственной меткой "окна"? Без конкретики, хочется обе метки просто удалить.

Comment: @Kromster 1) Вопросов с этими двумя метками в сумме 85 штук 2) Вопросы по разным ЯП: от `html` и `css` до `python`, `JS`, `c#` и `c++`

Comment: @Kromster Есть метка `java`(это язык программирования). А есть метка `swing`(это java-библиотека, входит в состав `jdk`). `swing` не может существовать без `java`, но это же не повод удалять эту метку. Вот и тут так же. Нужно сделать одну метку и дать ей описание, вот и всё.

Comment: @Зонтик если есть что-то общее между оконными системами - метка имеет шансы. Если Swing несамостоятельна и без Java не имеет смысла (в сочетании с другими метками), то на самом деле просится сделать java-swing. Но это спорно, поэтому я эту тему не поднимаю )

Comment: @αλεχολυτ у нас тут где-то были гайдлайны, в сторону выбора единственного или множественного числа для меток .. не могу найти

Comment: @Kromster Это был лишь пример, метку `swing` удалять конечно, не надо, она позволяет облегчить поиск по сайту. Я про то, что даже если метка не может существовать без другой, её необязательно выкидывать. А "окна" -независимы от ЯП или ОС

Comment: @Kromster [это?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327/176217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объединить (синонимизировать) однозначно стоит. При этом, я бы предложил сделать основной метку [окно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be). Т.к. это согласуется с enSO меткой [[window]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window), а множественное число в прямом переводе будет конфликтовать с названием популярной операционной системы, по которой уже есть тьма вопросов - [windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows).

Самому даже кажется, что [window](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/window) на ruSO тоже вполне может быть основной меткой. Хоть язык и не русский (а новые предложения законодателей иногда удивляют), но для разработчиков (даже русскоязычных) термин "window" вполне должен быть понятен.

Comment: А вы не могли бы объединить метки? А то у меня репутации на это не хватает, для этого нужно 2500 баллов репы, у меня пока только 841.

Comment: @Зонтик объединять метки единолично могут только модераторы. Обычные участники могут создавать голосования за синонимы и голосовать. Но для этого нужно иметь рейтинг по метке не менее 5, что тоже часто проблема. Нашёл вот такой [FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304152/339911), надо бы его бампнуть.